# Publishing Overwrites Edit Tracking Fields

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector, publishing

Is there a way to publish edit tracking enabled data from ArcMap (10.3.1) to a AGOL hosted service without having the edit tracking fields automatically overwritten with the time and user who published it? Looking to maintain the fields as they are in ArcMap, the data originally obtained via Collector.

Comment: yes share the data as a service to your AGOL organization via arcmap, this should not overwrite any data. If you want to test it preform the share of a copy of the data.

Comment: have you already tried this and it overwrites the tracking fields?

Comment: Yes, we published a geodatabase that already had editor and edit time fields, and the editor and edit time was overwritten to the username that published the data and the time that the data was published.

Comment: Do you ever get this resolved? I am also seeing an issue where publishing overwrites the edit tracking and creation fields. The issue seems to be with the hosted organization as it occurs in arcmap and arcgis pro.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're adding data from AGOL or Portal/Enterprise to ARCmap for desktop, making some edits and then publishing it back to AGOL/Portal?

If so, you don't want to publish it, you want to sync it.

Once you've added your AGOL-feature-service to ArcMap for desktop you can right click and "create a local copy for editing".  You then locate the local copy in your "featureservicelocaledits" folder (somewhere in your default ArcGIS folder structure).  Right-click>manage>disable editor tracking. Make all the edits you need and save the edits. Then enable editor tracking once more. You can now sync your local edits back to the server. Your editor tracking fields will be unchanged as it was disabled while you made the edits.